# Store session data alongside identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

When using identity, what is the best practice for storing multi-request, non-user specific data?

I have a feature that tracks the currently selected item for my logged in user, to do this I'm storing it in `Session["itemId"]`. However it is not cleared when I log out.

My research has led me to believe I should add a claim but this doesn't seem to be the right place. It is not user specific merely the current selection.  Also what if it was a more complex object I wanted to store.

Can I convince identity to clear session state on logout?

Comment: If "it's not user specific", why store it on `Session`?

Comment: Wrong wording perhaps, it's not a user attribute that makes up their identity (such as name).